# (Terraform, GCP) Error 400: Role roles/run.invoker is not supported for this resource., badRequest

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

On **GCP**, I'm trying to add **"Service Account 2"** as a member to **"Service Account 1"** with this **Terraform** code below:

```js
resource "google_service_account" "service_account_1" {
  display_name = "Service Account 1"
  account_id   = "service-account-1"
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account_2" {
  display_name = "Service Account 2"
  account_id   = "service-account-2"
}

resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "service_account_iam_binding" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account_1.name
  role               = "roles/run.invoker"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account_2.email}" 
  ]

  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.service_account_1,
    google_service_account.service_account_2
  ]
}
```

But I got this error below:

> Error applying IAM policy for service account
> 'projects/myproject-173831/serviceAccounts/service-account-1@myproject-173831.iam.gserviceaccount.com':
> Error setting IAM policy for service account
> 'projects/myproject-173831/serviceAccounts/service-account-1@myproject-173831.iam.gserviceaccount.com':
> googleapi: Error 400: Role roles/run.invoker is not supported for this
> resource., badRequest

Are there any mistakes with my **Terraform** code?

Answer (score 2):

**Service Account** doesn't support **"roles/run.invoker"**. So of course the service account **"Service Account 1"** doesn't support "roles/run.invoker". Only **Cloud Run** supports **"roles/run.invoker"**.

If you really want to add **"Service Account 2"** as a member to **"Service Account 1"**, you can use **"roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"** or  **"roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"**.

**"google_service_account_iam_binding"** with **"roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"**:

```js
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "service_account_iam_binding" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account_1.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser" // Here

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account_2.email}" 
  ]

  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.service_account_1,
    google_service_account.service_account_2
  ]
}
```

**"google_service_account_iam_binding"** with **"roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"**:

```js
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "service_account_iam_binding" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account_1.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin" // Here

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account_2.email}" 
  ]

  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.service_account_1,
    google_service_account.service_account_2
  ]
}
```

In addition, you can use **"google_service_account_iam_member"** with **"roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"** or  **"roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"** instead of **"google_service_account_iam_binding"**.

**"google_service_account_iam_member"** with **"roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"**:

```js
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "service-account-iam_member" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account_1.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account_2.email}"

  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.service_account_1,
    google_service_account.service_account_2
  ]
}
```

**"google_service_account_iam_member"** with **"roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"**:

```js
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "service-account-iam_member" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account_1.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account_2.email}"

  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.service_account_1,
    google_service_account.service_account_2
  ]
}
```

Finally, you can add **"Service Account 2"** as a member to **"Service Account 1"**.